# Jquery finding natural language dates in strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, nlp

I'm making booking software for a live show. My performers often send me multiple dates that they're available. I'm dealing with lots of performers and lots of dates where there could be conflicting bookings. I want the app to be able to look at all the dates and find all the conflicts.

I would love it if I could copy and paste their email text into a form field and have jquery find the dates to process them. Is there an existing system for doing this? It would have to be smart. Here are some examples of emails I recieve and the arrays I would like returned from javascript...

> I can do: Aug. 29, 2018 Sep. 5, 2018 Sep. 19, 2018

`{"2018-08-29","2018-09-05","2018-09-19"}`

> I'm available 10/9 and 11/2

```
{"2018-10-09","2018-11-02"}
```

> How about Sept 8 & 15?

```
{"2018-09-08","2018-09-15"}
```

> Can we do next wednesday and Nov 9?

```
{"2018-08-29","2018-11-09"}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? If you want to parse datetime's out from a string, use a datetime library instead.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 it has to do with jQuery because I'm looking for a javascript / jQuery solution for quickly processing text. Did I ask this wrong?

Comment: You should use the right tool for the right task. jQuery is not a library that understands datetime, so "using jQuery to parse datetime" does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You formats are way to "open" so finding something that would work for all of these would be tricky. You could look into https://dateparser.io/. They seem to support a wide range of cases as you can [see here](https://dateparser.io/documentation.html#supported).

Some examples:

`December 15th, 2010`, `15th of December`, `2010-12-15` ...

Also relative dates:

`last friday`, `today`, `a day from now` etc.